# ISQL - exporting column with very long text

Tags: export, sybase, isql

I have a table in sybase database running on Solaris, which I like to export. The table contains a column which is of IMAGE type and it contains very long text ( 100000+ chars). I'm not able to export it properly, because isql splits the lines in the output.

So far I've been trying with `-w` option in isql command line and also with textsize option within SQL, but no success so far.

I used isql with `-o <filename>` option to store query results in the file. I also tried

SELECT * from tablename OUTPUT TO "filename"

but this doesn't work for me.

Is there any hidden limitation of column width in isql or maybe some other display/screen/output settings which need to be adjusted ?
Or is there maybe a way to compress that column, so its not that long ?

Comment: I solved the problem.  Some more fine-tunning with " -w " and " textsize " options was needed. The idea is that -w looks like width of complete output line and textsize is maz size of a column, so -w must bi bigger than all column sizes together. Didn't realize that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isql` is not intended to be used to export data from the database, but to display data interactively to a client.

If you need to export data, use the `bcp` utility.  If you need to execute query logic as part of the export, you can create a view that contains the information you need, and export from that view.

Comment: doesn't explicitly answer my question, but it is a good hint anyway. There is a kind of export functionality in isql so tried to use it. But defintely will try your method.